# CSS issue in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have simple web page and that banner contains three images. I want to expand the banner when different resolutions.my solution is working on Firefox and Chrome but not IE7.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        #left{width:338px; height:103px; float:left; background-image:url('image/banner_left.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
        .middle{float:left; background-image:url('image/banner_middle.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
        #right{width:620px; height:103px; float:right; background-image:url('image/banner_right.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div id="container" class="middle"  style="float:left;">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="middle" class="middle"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="content" style="clear:both; float:left;"></div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any idea?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you post screenshot or link to a screenshot pointing out what's wrong?

Comment: what I want is left and right images should be in the left and the right position of the screen and middle image should be expanded(repeat) according to the screen size(width). problem is middle image repeat just after right image in IE7 @Shadow Wizard

Comment: I fear you'll have to use JavaScript and set the middle div width to the width of the body minus width of two other `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width` value in `.middle` in percents.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example and assuming you want any content under the banner this is one way you can do it:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        #banner{
            background:url('image/banner_middle.jpg') ;
            background-repeat:repeat-x;
        }
        #left{
            width:338px;
            height:103px;
            float:left;
            background-image:url('image/banner_left.jpg');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        #right{
            width:620px;
            height:103px;
            float:right;
            background-image:url('image/banner_right.jpg');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        .clearFloat{
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div id="banner">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div class="clearFloat"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Any content goes here
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what I want is left and right images should be in the left and the right position of the screen and middle image should be expanded(repeat) according to the screen size(width). problem is middle image repeat just after right image in IE7